# What area is considered to be Marseille's city centre?

Tags: france, nightlife, marseille

Since I am travelling in Marseille by the end of this month and have no idea whatsoever of the city it would be good if you guys had any information to share with me.

It would be useful to know where the centre of the city where the nightlife clubs and bars are located.

Comment: Well, you could start with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marseille#Central_Marseille

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always hard to really tell where the centre of a city is. Regarding Marseille, I would say that the area covered in [that map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/43.2958/5.3768) more or less contains the city centre.

This includes the [Vieux-Port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Port_of_Marseille), a touristy area (center of the map), Le Panier, a bucolic neighborhood (north-west of the map), the St-Charles train/bus station (north-east of the map), la [Canebière](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canebi%C3%A8re) (a famous long street, always busy and with many shops) (east of the map), and at the western end you will also have the Mucem, a recent museum.

Comment: Thanks! I also like to the fact that you used OSM for the map link ;)